# While using expression in DataTables.Columns.Add the ColumnName is wrong

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Example code of adding a new column to a DataTable:

```
var test = "HELLO";
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));

dt.Columns.Add("Combined", typeof(string), $"'{test}_'+B+'_'+C");
```

When I write the table to e.g. SQL DB or Excel the name of the new added column is `"Combined + the expression"`. Even when I expand the column names in the debugger the wrong value appears.

How can I solve that the column name is `"Combined"` as defined in the `Add` method?

Similar issue: [Link](https://forum.uipath.com/t/while-using-expression-in-datatable-the-column-is-changing/299976)

Comment: "When I write the table to SQL DB" you don't show code where you write to the DB

Comment: @TimSchmelter This has nothing to do with SQL, but with the column name itself. It's the same with writing the table to e.g. Excel. If you expand the column names in the debugger it shows also the wrong value.

Comment: These are different topics anyway. The debugger just shows what  `column.ToString` returns and that has nothing to do with what is written to the DB, because that's the task of a `SqlDataAdapter` or `SqlCommand`. If you look at the `ColumnName` property of the `DataColumn` it's still `"Combined"`. So in the code that you've shown i don't see any issues.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You were right. I had column instead of column.ColumnName in my SQL insert query. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usage of columns in the statement e.g. in SQL create was wrong.

Instead of :

```
$"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"tableName\" ({string.join(",", columns.Select(c => $"\"{c}\" text"))});";
```

use c.ColumnName:

```
$"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"tableName\" ({string.join(",", columns.Select(c => $"\"{c.ColumnName}\" text"))});";
```